# getting the the field value based on the other value you entered in a form django

Tags: python, django, django-forms

two models:

```
class Branch(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    square = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    branch_id = models.CharField(max_length=5, blank=True)

class Worker(models.Model):
    w_branch = models.ForeignKey(Branch, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True, blank=True)
```

Form

```
class PayForm(forms.Form):
    branch = forms.ModelChoiceField(label='branch', queryset=Branch.objects.all())
    worker = forms.ModelChoiceField(label='customer', queryset=Worker.objects.filter())
```

I don`t know how to get queryset of workers based on branch choise whithin the form. And i`m not sure that it is possible...can you help?

for instance I have 3 branches, and each one of them has 3 workers. If i write queryset=Worker.objects.all(), I get all workers in all branches. But i`m trying to get workers based on user's choise of branch. For instance, If user chooses first branch he can choose in field "worker" only workers from first branch

Comment: It is not very clear what you mean, perhaps you want a dependent dropdown? See this tutorial https://simpleisbetterthancomplex.com/tutorial/2018/01/29/how-to-implement-dependent-or-chained-dropdown-list-with-django.html

Comment: for instance I have 3 branches, and each one of them has 3 workers. If i write queryset=Worker.objects.all(), I get all workers in all branches. But i`m trying to get workers based on user's choise of branch. For instance, If user chooses first branch he can choose in field "worker" only workers from first branch

Answer (score 0):

There is a good package for that already: Django Smart Selects.

https://github.com/jazzband/django-smart-selects

On the documentation it is called chained selects.

https://django-smart-selects.readthedocs.io/en/latest/usage.html#chained-selects